# How to get URL from the text

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get URL from the text?

For example:

```
string Text = "this is text with url http://test.com";
```

I have to get url and set it to other variable. How can I do this with ASP.NET?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218863/find-url-in-plain-text-and-insert-html-a-markups next do a little bit of research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the previous answers, you can do this as well:

```
string text = "this is text with url http://test.com";
Match match = Regex.Match(text, @"http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$");

// gets you http://test.com
string url = match.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

String.Split Method (String[], StringSplitOptions)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

You can find examples: C# - C++ - F# - VB

> [ComVisibleAttribute(false)]
>   public string[] Split(
>       string[] separator,
>       StringSplitOptions options
>   )

In this case, "http://" can be a good string for separator.

Answer (score 1):

```
reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
```

This is the regex to find the URL from Text.

Hope Its Helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
string _Url = "this is text with url http://test.com";

MatchCollection _Match = Regex.Matches(_Url , @"http.+)([\s]|$)");
string _Address= _Match[0].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use

"/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\://[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?/"

as regular expression for your search...
;)

Answer (score 1):

```
string url = Text.Substring(Text.IndexOf("http://"));
```